# SBT: How to include sbt files in upper directory to my build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a many dependent sbt projects in one folder. They all have same values in `Build.sbt`, for example dependencies.

I want to move same values from all sbt files to separate file. But don't want to use multibuild. Just need to include some other sbt files from upper directory.

For example my directory structure can look like this:

```
MyRepository
  |- Dependencies.sbt
  |- MyProject1
      |- src
      |- Build.sbt
  |- MyProject2
      |- src
      |- Build.sbt
```

In that example, how can I include `Dependencies.sbt` in `Build.sbt`?

Answer (score 0):

Code is reused between .sbt files by creating a normal .scala file in project/. The code in project/ will be available for use in the .sbt files.

If I remember correctly the definitions in one .sbt are not visible to other .sbt files, at least on the older versions.

Basically, the solution is to use: `Dependencies.scala` and not `Dependencies.sbt` and define the common part's there.

Check the illustration, that can be found [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html),

You create project/Dependencies.scala to track dependencies in one place.

```scala
    import sbt._

    object Dependencies {
      // Versions
      lazy val akkaVersion = "2.3.8"

      // Libraries
      val akkaActor = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
      val akkaCluster = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion
      val specs2core = "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.4.17"

      // Projects
      val backendDeps =
        Seq(akkaActor, specs2core % Test)
    }
```

The `Dependencies` object will be available in `build.sbt`.
You need to,  `import Dependencies._` in your `build.sbt` file.

```scala
    import Dependencies._

    ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
    ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

    lazy val backend = (project in file("backend"))
      .settings(
        name := "backend",
        libraryDependencies ++= backendDeps
      )
```

Comment: So, I already checked out SBT "Organizing Build" page. But, It's about a multi-build projects. And in that way (what I see), I can't import and build a project separately from the other ones. But I want to. So, for me that way is useless.

Comment: Also, if we talking about solution with Dependencies.scala, may be you can give me example, how to import scala file in sbt file, when the scala file is in upper directory than sbt. I mean scala file probably not in class path.

Comment: I can't see why the object will not be in classpath. If you have an example that we can try it would be easier to check what is the issue.